# how to change child component state in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I came across the following problem: I need to use another component's function inside a component:

header.js

```
export default function Header() {

  const [showModalLogin ,setShowModalLogin] = useState(false);

  return(
    <>
    <span>Hi,  <Link onClick={() =>{ setShowModalLogin(true)}}>login</Link> </span>
    {showModalLogin ? <LoginModal setShowModalLogin={setShowModalLogin}/> : ''}
    </>
  );
}
```

home.js

```
import Header from '../../components/header/header';

export default function Home() {

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Link onClick={() =>{ setShowModalLogin(true)}}>open login</Link>
    </>
}
```

How do I do in home.js to call the setShowModalLogin function that is in header.js ? I'm trying to use the context api too, but I still can't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just place useState in Header component and pass setShowModalLogin as props:

```js
import Header from '../../components/header/header';

export default function Home() {
  const [isShowModalLogin ,setShowModalLogin] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Header isShowModalLogin={isShowModalLogin} setShowModalLogin={setShowModalLogin} />
      <Link onClick={() => setShowModalLogin(true)}>open login</Link>
    </>
}
```

```js
export default function Header({ isShowModalLogin, setShowModalLogin }) {
  return(
    <>
    <span>Hi,  <Link onClick={() => setShowModalLogin(true)}>login</Link> </span>
    {isShowModalLogin ? <LoginModal setShowModalLogin={setShowModalLogin}/> : ''}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Nice! But I will have other pages like home.js and I will have to include const [isShowModalLogin ,setShowModalLogin] = useState(false); in all pages. There must be another way to do it.

Comment: I will right the answer in a new one

Answer (score 0):

Then you can do it in this way:

1. Create Context
2. Save useState inside
3. Use it everywhere you need

```js
export const YourContext = createContext();

export const YourProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isShowModalLogin, setShowModalLogin] = useState(false);

  const value = {
    isShowModalLogin,
    setShowModalLogin
  };

  return <YourContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</YourContext.Provider>;
}
```

```js
// App.js

const App = () => {
  return (
    <YourProvider>
      <AppContent />
    </YourProvider>
  )
}
```

So now you can use it like here:

```js
import Header from '../../components/header/header';

export default function Home() {
  const { isShowModalLogin, setShowModalLogin } = useContext(YourContext);

  return (
    <>
      <Header isShowModalLogin={isShowModalLogin} setShowModalLogin={setShowModalLogin} />
      <Link onClick={() => setShowModalLogin(true)}>open login</Link>
    </>
}
```